# MDX count number of days with Invoice amount greater than 0

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I wish to great a calculated measure "Dispatch days" in SSAS Visual Studios that counts the number of days where there has been a sales transaction made, i.e Invoice Amount greater than 0. So if I look at 2018 it should give me the number of days that year, where there were sales.
I tried using this

```
COUNT(Filter(
           Descendants([D_Time].[Year-Month-Day].currentmember,[D_Time]. 
           [Year-Month-Day].[Day]),[Measure].[Invoice Amount LOC] >0
 ))
```

but it only gives me null.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: how did you pass the year in your query, I presume you had year in one of the axis.

Comment: I placed the year level and then calculated measure that I created

Comment: Can you share your entire query

Comment: I have a Time dimension that consists of a hierarchy that looks like this Year, Month, Day.  So I just wish to count the number of days in the Hierarchy

Comment: What i meant was, that for which query did is return null, by the looks of it, it will only return results when a member of year level is passed/selected. I understand you want to count the number of days, but Cube wants to know for which year you want this?

Comment: Well Im in the browser mode in Visual studios, so I "drag & drop" the Year level and then next to it the calculated measure "Dispatch days"

Comment: I am trying right now to switch [D_Time].[Year-Month-Day].currentmember,[D_Time]. 
           [Year-Month-Day].[Day] to  [D_Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Year],[D_Time]. 
           [Year-Month-Day].currentmember

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202738/discussion-between-moazrub-and-rubrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be, however I suppose that a year is specified in one of the axis

```
count(nonempty(Descendants([D_Time].[Year-Month-Day].currentmember,[D_Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day]),[Measure].[Invoice Amount LOC]))
```